# Is there a way to count the number of discord messages for other users in my server?

Tags: server, discord, message, communication

I am trying to count total messages for each coach in my server but they send direct messages instead of the actual server, is there a way to count total messages from direct messages from people within my server?

Hoping there is some bot or api of some sort to be able to count total messages

Comment: I think that you don't have any control over direct messages, but I might be wrong.  But since those messages can be done with or without being on your server, at the time the message was created, no log was made that it happened in which to increment to count.   Although if it is possible, it raises some privacy concerns.

Comment: @easleyfixed -- i was talking to someone from another competitor of ours and they told me they were able to do it so i was quite curious!

Comment: Interesting and disturbing, curious to see if you find something out.